# Shader - Specular Glitter-Sparkling effect

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shader, hlsl

I am trying to create a glittering effect for my realtime shader but I don't find any good ressources to help me.

Here are an example:
[image]

Are there some white paper or tutorial about such effect ?

What is the principle of this effect ?

Comment: you will probably find an answer at gamedev.stackexchange,com instead of here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an interesting article [AMD - Getting Procedural](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/Shopf-Procedural.pdf).

It seems that sparkles are harder than I think.
Decent solution: Use 3D position to index 3D noise function, add the view vector, use frac function to further randomize things.

Sparkle:

```
float specBase = saturate(dot(reflect(-normalize(viewVec), normal),
lightDir));
// Perturb a grid pattern with some noise and with the view-vector
// to let the glittering change with view.
float3 fp = frac(0.7 * pos + 9 * Noise3D( pos * 0.04).r + 0.1 * viewVec);
fp *= (1 - fp);
float glitter = saturate(1 - 7 * (fp.x + fp.y + fp.z));
float sparkle = glitter * pow(specBase, 1.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this be something as simple as texture mapping with a normal map and a specular map. The normal map to give the glitter some "height" and the the specular map to make them "shiney" when the light is at the necessary angle?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before with a threshold followed by a couple of blurs and then a blend. In my case it was an interactive shader for stylizing video, so the controls were adjustable, but for something like a game you could probably set them statically.

First you threshold the input image, so everything with luminance below the threshold is set to transparent black (RGBA = 0,0,0,0). Everything with equal or greater luminance than the threshold remains as it is.

Next you apply a directional blur to the thresholded image.

Then apply a directional blur that's pointing 90° from the previous one to the thresholded image. (Note - do not apply it to the already blurred image. This is important! You should end up with 3 images - thresholded image, blurred image, and another blurred image where the blur is 90° from the first.)

Finally, using a simple additive blend, add the 2 blurred images to the *original* input. (You can now throw out the thresholded image.) The result will be that every pixel that has a luminance above the threshold will now have a sparkly cross on it. You can use more than 2 blurs if you want and adjust their angles so you get 3 or 5 or more points, but it means more passes.

**Edit**: One thing I forgot to mention - in your videos, it looks like they added a texture of random white dots distributed over the object to give it a glitter-like look.

Also, the above filtering process should be applied in screen-space.

Comment: This is not the effect I am looking for. The effect I am trying to create is the white dots distributed over the object that gives the glitter-like look.

Comment: I believe that the white dots are just a texture with random white dots in it, and then they apply a filter like the above one as a post process in screenspace.

Comment: I've changed the example to show the effect. The white dots are the effect I am trying to reproduce.